# Why is vegan cheese nicknamed Gary?

Tags: veganism, dairy-substitutes, terminology, uk

I have a friend who is a vegan and for some reason she, and many other people, seem to call Vegan cheese Gary.

**Why is vegan cheese nicknamed Gary though? Where did this come from?**

I am from the UK by the way, so this may be only applicable to the UK.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This started as a reaction to a rant from one dairy lover who was offended by vegan cheese being called cheese. [Excerpt from the rant suggesting the vegan cheese being called Gary](http://www.standard.co.uk/news/uk/vegan-cheese-renamed-gary-after-one-dairylovers-facebook-rant-goes-viral-a3360021.html):

> "Call it Gary or something just don't call it
>   cheese because it's not cheese!"

The relevant part of the rant as an image is here.

[image]

The internet responded and so did the real world. Facebook page called ['It's not Vegan Cheese, it's Gary'](https://www.facebook.com/veganslovegary/) has started and it collects humorous images and memes about vegan cheese being Gary.

[image]

Some supermarkets follow the trend as well - for example Sainsbury's (a grocery shop for those that are not from the UK) launched this ad on Facebook:

[image]

So **vegan cheese is called Gary because of one particular non-vegan having first-world problems about the implication of it being cheese**.

Comment: Also, this blatantly ignores that tofu variations have been called "soy cheeses" long before mainstream western veganism...

Comment: I don't like the term "Gary" because it seems to be taking the mickey. But a term other than "cheese" for vegan replacements for cheese doesn't seem to be a bad idea if we want to avoid using language that condones the eating of animal products. But I am the sort of person who calls meat "dead animal" and meat eaters "flesh eaters" (which in both cases is what they are). I dislike terms such as "quorn chicken".